# How can I add drivers for the Aopen XC cube to ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I have an old Aopen XCcube machine and I can only get 800x600 to work on any of my monitors. This is the output from lspci | grep VGS VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 661/741/760 PCI/AGP or 662/761Gx PCIE VGA Display Adapter

Is there anyway to install the drivers for this and get it to work? or is there any other way to get the resolution higher?

Comment: I did what this guy did for his SIS adapter and it Worked !!! http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2060174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what this guy did for his SIS and created a conf.d folder with configuation files that match my monitor's resolution.

ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2060174